# Why my Gradient is wrong (Coursera, Logistic Regression, Julia)?

Tags: gradient, julia, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I'm trying to do Logistic Regression from Coursera in Julia, but it doesn't work.

The Julia code to calculate the Gradient:

```
sigmoid(z) = 1 / (1 + e ^ -z)

hypotesis(theta, x) = sigmoid(scalar(theta' * x))

function gradient(theta, x, y)
    (m, n) = size(x)
    h = [hypotesis(theta, x[i,:]') for i in 1:m]
    g = Array(Float64, n, 1)
    for j in 1:n
        g[j] = sum([(h[i] - y[i]) * x[i, j] for i in 1:m])
    end
    g
end
```

If this gradient used it produces the wrong results. Can't figure out why, the code seems like the right one.

The [full Julia script](https://gist.github.com/apetrushin/e0ec98ca36cb3a668b081718ba47c1e0). In this script the optimal Theta calculated using my Gradient Descent implementation and using the built-in Optim package, and the results are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried comparing `gradient()` in the OP's code with numerical derivative of `cost_j()` (which is the objective function of minimization) using the following routine

```
function grad_num( theta, x, y )
    g = zeros( 3 )

    eps = 1.0e-6
    disp = zeros( 3 )

    for k = 1:3
        disp[:] = theta[:]

        disp[ k ]= theta[ k ] + eps
        plus = cost_j( disp, x, y )
        disp[ k ]= theta[ k ] - eps
        minus = cost_j( disp, x, y )

        g[ k ] = ( plus - minus ) / ( 2.0 * eps )
    end
    return g
end
```

But the gradient values obtained from the two routines do no seem to agree very well (at least for the initial stage of minimization)... So I manually derived the gradient of `cost_j( theta, x, y )`, from which it seems that the division by `m` is missing:

```
#/ OP's code
# g[j] = sum( [ (h[i] - y[i]) * x[i, j] for i in 1:m ] )

#/ modified code
  g[j] = sum( [ (h[i] - y[i]) * x[i, j] for i in 1:m ] ) / m
```

Because I am not very sure if the above code and expression are really correct, could you check them by yourself...?

But in fact, regardless of whether I use the original or corrected gradients, the program converges to the same minimum value (0.2034977016, almost the same as obtained from Optim), because the two gradients differ only by a multiplicative factor! Because the convergence was very slow, I also modified the stepsize `alpha` adaptively following the suggestion by Vincent (here I used more moderate values for acceleration/deceleration):

```
function gradient_descent(x, y, theta, alpha, n_iterations)
    ... 
    c = cost_j( theta, x, y )

    for i = 1:n_iterations
        c_prev = c
        c = cost_j( theta, x, y )

        if c - c_prev < 0.0
            alpha *= 1.01
        else
            alpha /= 1.05
        end
        theta[:] = theta - alpha * gradient(theta, x, y)
    end
    ...
end
```

and called this routine as

```
optimal_theta = gradient_descent( x, y, [0 0 0]', 1.5e-3, 10^7 )[ 1 ]
```

The variation of `cost_j` versus iteration steps is plotted below.[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are correct, the gradient should be divided by `m`. The strange thing though is that in the original example made with the Octave the gradient expected to be converging about 400 iterations. I will double check the original code, maybe they use some tricks to speed it up.

Answer (score 5):

The gradient is correct (up to a scalar multiple, as @roygvib points out). The problem is with the gradient descent.

If you look at the values of the cost function during your gradient descent, you will see a lot of `NaN`,
which probably come from the exponential:
lowering the step size (e.g., to `1e-5`) will avoid the overflow,
but you will have to increase the number of iterations a lot (perhaps to `10_000_000`).

A better (faster) solution would be to let the step size vary.
For instance, one could multiply the step size by `1.1`
if the cost function improves after a step
(the optimum still looks far away in this direction: we can go faster),
and divide it by `2` if it does not (we went too fast and ended up past the minimum).

One could also do a line search in the direction of the gradient to find the best step size
(but this is time-consuming and can be replaced by approximations, e.g., Armijo's rule).

Rescaling the predictive variables also helps.